# gives me this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Triangle.<init>(DD)V at testTriangle.main(testTriangle.java:6)

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, instance

First the error was that the variables in the parameters of the object is not initialized. Then it started to give this error when initialized, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Triangle.(DD)V
    at testTriangle.main(testTriangle.java:6). Please help!

```
// main class
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class testTriangle{
       public static void main(String [] args){
          double xcoord = 0,ycoord = 0;
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          Triangle object = new Triangle(xcoord,ycoord);

          System.out.println("Welcome to the hypothenuse finder!");
          System.out.println("Please input the first value(x): ");
          xcoord = scan.nextDouble();




          System.out.println("Please input the second value(y): ");
          ycoord = scan.nextDouble();

          object.radi();
          object.toString();
        }
    }

    import java.lang.Math.*;
    public class Triangle{
       double x;
       double y;

       public Triangle(double xcoord,double ycoord){
          x = xcoord;
          y = ycoord;
       }
       public double radi(){
          return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2)));

       }
       public void toString(){
          System.out.printf("The x value is: " + x + " the y value is: " + y + " and the radius is : ", radi());
       }

    }
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that the error message changes before your eyes!  You must have made changes to the code and/or environment.

Comment: is your code compiling?

Comment: Recompile the two classes at once. You seem to be running a new version of testTriangle with an old version of Triangle. And please respect the Java naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: code does not compile because it highlights the object i created and says there is a error

Comment: Is the "TestTriangle" class and "Triangle" class in different files? if not then make 2 files one called "TestTriangle" and the other called "Triangle". and then try to run it. Also change the "toString()" method name to "string()" or something, because the is a built in method called "toString()".

Comment: yes thank you I realized that after. The code complies and works just had to fix that little error.

Comment: In a typical program you wouldn't do this but multiple classes in one file can be useful for coding challenge practice. FIX: Remove the keyword public from both classes. Also make sure you do not have other classes with the same name in other files in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have got your code to work, by putting the 2 classes into there own class files and I also changed this method `toString()` name, because there is already a built in method called `toString()`. So I changed it to `string()` and it seems to work.

TestTriangle Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestTriangle{
   public static void main(String [] args){
      double xcoord = 0,ycoord = 0;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      Triangle object = new Triangle(xcoord,ycoord);

      System.out.println("Welcome to the hypothenuse finder!");
      System.out.println("Please input the first value(x): ");
      xcoord = scan.nextDouble();




      System.out.println("Please input the second value(y): ");
      ycoord = scan.nextDouble();

      object.radi();
      object.string();
    }
}
```

Triangle Class:

```
public class Triangle {
 double x;
 double y;

 public Triangle(double xcoord,double ycoord){
    x = xcoord;
    y = ycoord;
 }
 public double radi(){
    return(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2)));

 }

 public void string(){
    System.out.printf("The x value is: " + x + " the y value is: " + y + " and the radius is : ", radi());
 }
}
```